# App doesn't work anymore after Ionic CLI update

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-cli

After I updated Ionic CLI, 2 days ago, all the ionic components like `<ion-header-bar>` or `<ion-toggle>` aren't shown and the `ngCordova` plugin stopped working.

I tried, to uninstall and reinstall ionic, I tried to make a new project to test those tags, but even in the new project they aren't shown. When I run the `ionic serve --lab` command, there are no errors displayed.

What am I missing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after 3 days of research, I just found the solution. If one day somebody has this problem and view this post... just change the web browser xD